# jQuery: stop animation that is delayed, before it is triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm foolin around with the jquery hover functionality. the current code snippet looks like this:

```
$leftColumn.children().first().hover(
    function(event) {
        var $this = jQuery(this);
        $this.css({
            'background-color': '#505050'
        }).parent().stop()
        .animate(
            {
                'z-index': '999',
                width: '220px'
            },
            {
                duration: '1000'
            }
        );
    },
    function(event) {
        var $this = jQuery(this);
        $this.parent().stop()
        .animate(
            {
                width: '38px',
                'z-index': '1'
            },
            {
                duration: '1500',
                complete: function() {
                    $this.css({
                        'background-color': 'transparent'
                    });
                }
            }
        );
    }
);
```

What this basically does is increasing the width of a div (which is position absolute) to overlay another div.

I choosed to use jQuerys `animate()` functionality instead of CSS3s transition because I want to trigger a callback whenever the closing (decreasing the width again) animation is done.

My problem now is, that I want to delay the closing animation for 2 seconds (and yes I know about the `delay()` vs `setTimeout()` discussion) which worked fine with `setTimeout()`. However as the animation is timed out for the given duration it will run, even if I enter the hoverable area again. This of course makes sense as the `stop()` only triggeres while an animation is on the go, which is not the case if it is timed out.

How can I make this thing work (stop the closing animation when reentering the hoverable area) and still keep a timeout / delay before decreasing the width on "hover leave"?

Comment: Just a heads up, CSS3 transition/animations do have a callback. For transitions:

`$(".item").one("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function(){ ... });` and for animations:

`$(".item").one("animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd", function(){ ... });`

Comment: @BrettGregson ohh I didn't know that. thanks for the info and the reformatting of the question. I'll dig into that.

Comment: can its possible for you to create the fiddle or working snippet for this?

Comment: @BrettGregson I made it working with your suggestion to use CSS3 transition and the transitionEnd events. create an answer out of your comment and I will accept it as the correct one :)

Comment: @vijayP thanks for your effort, I made it working with the suggestion of Brett Gregson